# No gcc executable after pkg_add gcc on OpenBSD

Tags: gcc, openbsd

I installed gcc from packages on OpenBSD 6.5

`# pkg_add gcc-8.3.0`

gcc related files are installed at `/usr/local/lib/`, but no gcc executable is found.

`# gcc`
`-bash: gcc: command not found`

(I'm aware that Clang is commonly used on OpenBSD, but I want to use gcc for a project)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GNU C compiler executable is called `egcc` when it's installed from the `gcc` package. There should also be a `gcc` executable in `/usr/bin` (the `gcc` of the base system, at least on amd64).

```
$ type egcc gcc
egcc is /usr/local/bin/egcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
```

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.2.1 20070719
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ egcc --version
egcc (GCC) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

Note that `gcc` was removed from the OpenBSD base system on amd64 in late 2021 (OpenBSD 7.0).

Comment: Ok, that explains it.  I actually deleted /usr/bin/gcc because I thought it was an old version from packages.  Any idea how I could get the system gcc back in /usr/bin/gcc?

Comment: @sheepdog Ouch. I would probably boot from the `bsd.rd` kernel and do a system update with only the compiler set. Don't go deleting random files from the system. Also, the `pkg_delete` tool would never leave files behind, apart from modified configuration files.

Comment: If that is the single file you need to replace, there is no need to reinstall the whole set. Just download `comp65.tgz`, extract the file with `tar` (e.g. `tar xzf comp65.tgz /usr/bin/gcc`), check the ownership (`root:bin`) and permissions (`555`) and move it to `\usr\bin`.

Comment: @ZéLoff It's generally a bad idea to extract individual files from release sets, especially if you're on a snapshot release (the wrong libraries could be used). By updating the installation as a unit using the `bsd.rd` kernel (even if you update to the same release that you installed), you would not only guarantee that the base system was functional (with regards to permissions and libraries), but also that the correct release sets were used.  Also note that OpenBSD generally use forward slashes in pathnames.  It's _unfortunate_ that my previous comment said to only update the `comp` set.

Answer (score -3):

The gcc will be installed in /usr/local/bin
and the name of executable is (your architecture)_(your cpu)......gcc-(version of gcc)
if your system is x86_64 just type 'x8' on terminal andnhit tab key, it will show the full gcc executable name.